# How to satisfy nested wild card type match Class<?>

Tags: java

I have the following function

```
myFunction(Class<?> keyClass, Class<?> valueClass)
```

My value class have the following type

```
Map<MyClass1, MyClass2>
```

However when I pass the following

```
Map<MyClass1, MyClass2>.class
```

I get `cannot select from parameterized type` , does anyone know how to satisfy nested wild card generic type match?

Comment: After type erasure that wouldn't make sense. You'll need to show us more of what you are trying to do. A MCVE would be good.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Map.class` instead of `Map<MyClass1, MyClass2>.class`.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite vague. Considering only till what you have posted, I can say you will need to pass `Map.class` instead of `Map<Class1,Class2>`.

There is this concept called type erasure in java, where certain restrictions can be applicable only on compile time and and discarding type information at runtime.

If you are sure of map, you can write like

```
myFunction(Class<?> keyClass, Map<? extends YourSuperClass, ? extends YourSuperClass> map)
```

Notice that the second argument you pass is a Map and not Class.

Other way would be parameterized types,

```
public static <T, K, V> void myFunction(Class<T> keyClass, Map<K,V> map)
```

All these depend on what you want to achieve in myFunction();